# Why doesn't my list comprehension code sort things immediately?

Tags: python, nltk

My question: Why do I have to evaluate the code twice for it to actually work? I want to filter just the scores that are above 20. I don't know why I have to evaluate it twice for it to actually work. There is a lag where the cp doesn't seem to realize that I've changed which document to use (doclist[3] versus doclist[4]). If i've made such a change to doclist[4], the code initially outputs he results based on doclist[3]. And I have to evaluate it again, for me to get the results for doclist[4]

```
fw_2 = filterwords(doclist[3])
scored = finder.score_ngrams(bgm.likelihood_ratio)
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(fw_2)
# only bigrams that appear 3+ times
finder.apply_freq_filter(2)

fw_2 = [i for i in scored[0:20] if i[1] > 15]
```

example output.

```
[(('social', 'entrepreneurship'), 127.45178656939063),
 (('business', 'school'), 99.39518918596669),
 (('skoll', 'foundation'), 89.99535318543879),
 (('skoll', 'centre'), 79.35035637864716),
 (('said', 'business'), 75.04493764654694),
 (('silicon', 'valley'), 67.94234171558752),
 (('world', 'forum'), 54.48210837540238),
 (('issues', 'schools'), 48.55122043259024),
```

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `scored` *after* you apply the filter to `finder`:

```
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(fw_2)
# only bigrams that appear 3+ times
finder.apply_freq_filter(2)
scored = finder.score_ngrams(bgm.likelihood_ratio)
fw_2 = [i for i in scored[0:20] if i[1] > 15]
```

You have to run your code twice because the changes to `finder` that take place after defining `scored` do not affect `scored`.

Comment: great. this did it haha. how did you know to do that? you're just familiar with the software?

Comment: I was guessing, based on the symptom you described. I could have been wrong if `scored` was an object that had a reference to `finder`. But it seemed plausible that `score_ngrams` returned a simple object such as a list *with no reference to `finder`*. If that's the case, then no matter what happens to `finder`, `scored` will not change.